# Tkinter switching frame with conditions

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6, frame

I use following code: 
[Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        self.giris = tk.Entry(self)
        self.giris.pack()
        self.yazi = tk.Label(self, text="Buraya GİRİLEN VERİ gelecek.")
        self.yazi.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="ae",
                        command=lambda: [self.alinanmetin(), controller.show_frame("PageOne")])
        button2.pack()

    def alinanmetin(self):
        il = self.giris.get()
        self.yazi.config(text="Girdiğiniz il: %s" % il)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry("600x400")
    app.mainloop()
```

I want to change my frame according to the value I get from the entry.

if(il =="ali") i want change my frame and 

if( il != "ali") i dont want do anything.

I am currently running two functions at the same time.How can i change frame after check value.

Comment: Whats wrong with your `def alinanmetin(...`?

Comment: @stovfl 
I want to change the frame according to the provincial data here.

Comment: ***I want to change ... according to the provincial data***: Yes, what is stopping you to use `if il == "ali":`

Comment: How can i use this  `controller.show_frame("StartPage"))`  ** if il == "ali" **

Comment: You have to put into the `def alinanmetin(...` ...